# Is it possible to use simple triggers to increment a cell whenever another cell is edited in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the desired behavior:

1. Cell A1 contains a number (0 by default) representing damage taken.
2. Cells B1:D1 contain checkboxes (FALSE by default).
3. When cell B1 is edited (i.e. checked "TRUE"), cell A1 is decreased by 1. Cell B1 is automatically reset to FALSE. If cell A1 is decreased below 0, it is reset to 0).
4. When cell C1 is edited, cell A1 is incremented by 1 and automatically reset to FALSE.
5. When cell D1 is edited, cell A1 is reset to 0.

I'm very new to Google Apps Script and recently discovered Simple Triggers. It seems like onEdit is meant to trigger when anything in the entire workbook is edited, but I'm not sure. Is it possible for a script to run automatically if a specific range is edited (i.e. B1:D1 as described above)?

---

For context, I'm designing a character sheet for a play-by-post RPG. When a character takes damage, their capability in one or more skills is decreased by taking *damage ranks*. To make it as simple as possible to track these throughout the sheet, I'm trying to find a way to easily increment these ranks up and down without having to write a separate macro for each row.

If there's a better solution than the behavior I've proposed (e.g. using something other than checkboxes and onEdit triggers), please let me know! Also, it would be ideal if the solution also worked on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
Cell A1 contains a number (0 by default) representing damage taken.
Cells B1:D1 contain checkboxes (FALSE by default).
When cell B1 is edited (i.e. checked "TRUE"), cell A1 is decreased by 1. Cell B1 is automatically reset to FALSE. If cell A1 is decreased below 0, it is reset to 0).
When cell C1 is edited, cell A1 is incremented by 1 and automatically reset to FALSE.
When cell D1 is edited, cell A1 is reset to 0.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;//might need to change Sheet1 to whatever you're using
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("B1");
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue((vA1-1<0)?0:vA1-1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("C1");
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-2).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(vA1+1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart===4 && e.range.rowStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("D1");
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(0);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

> Just a reminder: You can't run this function from the script editor just install it in a .gs file and play with your check boxes on Sheet1.  If you not using Sheet1 the change the name of the sheet in the script to whatever you sheet name is.

It looks like this will work for "A1:D".

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("B1");
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue((vA1-1<0)?0:vA1-1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("C1");
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-2).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(vA1+1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart===4 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("D1");
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(0);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Modified a bit to help you test it

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var cell=e.range.getA1Notation();//debug
  e.source.toast('Entry');//debug
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart<15 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast(cell);//debug
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue((vA1-1<0)?0:vA1-1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart<15 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast(cell);//debug
    var vA1=e.range.offset(0,-2).getValue();
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(vA1+1);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart===4 && e.range.rowStart<15 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast(cell);//debug
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(0);
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

> Please note: there should only be one onEdit(e) simple trigger function.  If fact there should only be one of any function in a .gs file.

You may wish to remove my `e.source.toast();` lines

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try this out. Do I need to duplicate this script for every row, or is there a way to use relative references so that A2:D behaves the same way?

Comment: If you're thinking that you can use this as a cell function, then you are incorrect.  This has to be run as a script that fires off of the onEdit trigger and receives the event object from the onEdit trigger.  Cell functions don't work that way and they have to return a value to their cell. Read more about Custom Functions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: It seems to work pretty well without the row .  Do you want it to work this way on more than one sheet?

Comment: No, it only needs to function in a single range (x number of rows, 4 columns) on a single sheet.

Comment: Okay, I added the `e.range.rowStart<15` so this will only work for rows less than 15 and you can change that any way you like.  I would probaly hard wire it so that it runs a fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks! You've been a huge help!

Comment: @JaredEvans Please accept the answer if it solved your issue, so others will find the solution easily.

Comment: It worked exactly as I intended, and was written clearly enough for an amateur like me to modify to suit my needs. Thank you SO much. This has been a helpful step for me in gaining a stronger understanding of Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

In This Example this trigger if for MainSheet, and cells of b, c and d are boolean type, not string:

```
function MainSheetOnEdit()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mysheet=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  if (mysheet.getSheetName()!='MainSheet') return;

  if(mysheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn()==2)
  {
    if (mysheet.getCurrentCell().getValue()==true){
       mysheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(false);
       if(mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).getValue()>0) 
       {
         mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).setValue(mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).getValue()-1);
       }
    }
  }

  if(mysheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn()==3)
  {
    if (mysheet.getCurrentCell().getValue()==true){
       mysheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(false);
       mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).setValue(mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2).getValue()+1);
    }
  }

  if(mysheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn()==4)
  {
    if (mysheet.getCurrentCell().getValue()==true){
       mysheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(false);
       mysheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -3).setValue(0);
    }
  }    
}
```